# ServiceDesk parsing email sent using smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Let me explain the situation: I send a letter using `smtplib` (code below) to `ServiceDesk`.
The letter looks like this:

```
Subject: ~Bot~ subject
Body:
~~OPERATION=AddRequest~~
~~REQUESTER=FULL NAME~~
```

It is written in the parameters of `ServiceDesk` that it parses the information that is in `~`. If you send a letter from mail (`Outlook` for example), then `ServiceDesk` parses everything normally, but if through `smtplib` it does not parse at all, the subject remains `~Bot~ subject` instead of `subject`, and the sender is not substituted from the `REQUESTER` parameter.

Code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

to = 'servicedesk@my-domain.com'
gmail_user = 'servicedesk@my-domain.com'
gmail_pwd = 'password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)

subject = "~Bot~ 123"

msg = MIMEText("~~OPERATION=AddRequest~~\r\n~~REQUESTER=FIO~~")
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject

smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_bytes())
smtpserver.close()
```

I tried to change the encoding when sending a message, but it didn't help. I also tried another library for sending letters, which also turned out to be unsuccessful. Perhaps I lack competence and I simply do not indicate some required parameter.

Tell me what the problem might be and how it can be fixed. Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: @tripleee i tried ```EmailMessage```, don`t work

Comment: The main problem is that we have no guidance for what ServiceDesk looks for in the receiving message. I can speculate that it wants a HTML message to work, but I have no way to test that. In the meantime, moving to `EmailMessage` is a good idea for other reasons.

Comment: Can you share (minimal) source of a message which works, and one which doesn't? (Unfortunately, Microsoft makes it very hard to get the exact source of a message. Save it as .EML and view it in Notepad, maybe?)

Comment: @tripleee the minimum message is already specified in the code ```~~OPERATION=AddRequest~~\r\n~~REQUESTER=name~~```. The thing is that if you send it through Outlook, then everything works fine, but if you send it using a script, it doesn’t.

Comment: Then both the answers you received should work. There is something you are not telling us. Again, can you share the source of the actually working Outlook message, with the full MIME structure intact?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `smtpserver.send_message(msg)`. That should serialize the message according to the "normal" convention.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html for more details.

### Full code

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

to = 'servicedesk@my-domain.com'
gmail_user = 'servicedesk@my-domain.com'
gmail_pwd = 'password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)

subject = "~Bot~ 123"

msg = MIMEText("""
~~OPERATION=AddRequest~~
~~REQUESTER=FIO~~
""")
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject

smtpserver.send_message(msg)
smtpserver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, this method did not help. Any other ideas what could be causing this problem?

Comment: My guess is incorrect coding or whitespaces/newline that the parser misses.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is most likely with the formatting of the email. When using smtplib, you are sending a plain text email without any formatting or special characters. Therefore, the ServiceDesk may not be able to parse the email correctly since it is looking for specific characters and formatting.

the solution is to use the email package to create a properly formatted email.

```
to = 'servicedesk@my-domain.com'
gmail_user = 'servicedesk@my-domain.com'
gmail_pwd = 'password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)

subject = "~Bot~ 123"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = "~~OPERATION=AddRequest~~\r\n~~REQUESTER=FIO~~"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
smtpserver.close()
```

This will create a multipart email with the body containing the formatting as requested by ServiceDesk. This should solve the issue and allow the ServiceDesk to parse the email correctly.

make sure to enable less secure apps in your Google account to be able to use smtplib.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, your answer didn't help, do you have any other suggestions?